# use particles of particle designer in the project or create particle that doesn't take too much memory

Tags: iphone, xcode, memory, animation, particles

I would like to know if it is possible to use the particles I have created in particle designer in my xcode project ( not cocos 2d project). if it is impossible how can I create a particle that doesn't take too much memory ( creating images in an array and make them move use too much memory and the animation slow down).Sorry for my english I'm french

Comment: `Sorry for my english. I'm french`. Your English is *très formidable!*

Comment: but can anyone respond ?